# Passing variables through classes in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, events

In my scenario I have 2 view controllers, one tied to the main view and one that is connected to the first one as a subview.

Now let's say that my App Delegate class wants to pass a string to the subview controller. What is the best practice to achieve this? If I wanted to pass it to the 1st controller i could just say something like

`[self.firstController getStringInCustomFunction:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"200%d", 9]];`

Also keep in mind that this call might have to be asynchronous.

Coming from ActionScript, normally I would just add and event listener and move my variables though events. What's the equivalent in objective-c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Coming from ActionScript, normally I would just add and event listener and move my variables though events. What's the equivalent in objective-c?*

Take a look at [`NSNotificationCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Specifically, [`postNotificationName:object:userInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:), wherein you create an [`NSNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that includes an [`NSDictionary`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of objects you pass inside `userInfo`.

On the other end, you have another object that is [registered to "hear" an NSNotification](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723) of a specific name. That other object calls whatever method is specified in the registration. You might unpackage the `userInfo` dictionary in this method, to retrieve the object of interest.